# Manipulating result from "system" call in C++ program

Tags: c++, linux, shell, console

Say that I execute some command to run in the terminal within a C++ program. For instance:

```
int main(){
std::system("./myprog");
return 0;
}
```

Assume that myprog produces some output that is printed to the console. Can I make use of this output within my C++ program? For example:

```
int main(){
some_var = std::system("./myprog");

if (some_var == "something")
  // Do something.

return 0;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) function:

```
FILE *fp = popen("./myprog", "r");

char buffer[128];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
{
    std::cout << "Output from program: " << buffer << '\n';
}

pclose(fp);
```

Comment: Hi Joachim, thanks for the speedy reply. In this context, what is "buffer"? Thanks!

Comment: @VincentRusso It's just a normal character buffer (see the [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) manual page).

Comment: popen opens a pipe between your program and the program you are spawing.  You read the output of the spawned pgm via the pipe.  Buffer is just some area of memory you are reading into e.g. char buffer[200];

Comment: I think he should use the normal pipe and fork commands instead of wrapper like popen. this would explain him the underlying logic properly. anyways for clarity and simplicity popen would be the preferred option.